# How to call wcf service with out added service reference using channel factory

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, service-reference, channelfactory

Can any one help me on this.
"How to call wcf service with out added service reference using channel factory".

I have used this code :

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("");
        ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory<IUnityServiceChannel>(binding, address);
        UnityServiceClient channel = new UnityServiceClient();
        string token = channel.GetSecurityToken(svcUsername, svcPassword);
```

But I want to create the IUnityServiceChannel run time. I don't have any information about the IUnityServiceChannel.

So can you help me how to crate interface using reflection or some thing else.

Comment: There is no point at creating an interface at runtime because none of your code will implement it. It is a bit unclear where your issue is and what you need.